# Should I mount my mac Truecrypt Volume elsewhere?

Tags: encryption, password-management, file-encryption, backup, truecrypt

I've read in various places to not mount your truecrypt volume in the same place as your Dropbox or Sugarsync folder. I believe this only matter for Mac/Linux, but I need some verification.

On a Mac, when I mount a container, it states that it's mounted at '/Volume/Container_Name'

Does that mean it's mounting inside the dropbox folder itself even though it says Volume?

Because when mounting, there's an option to mount to another folder, see screenshot here: http://cl.ly/1i3v2n2Y0G2e2102272k

So should I be mounting it to that other folder? If i don't choose that folder, will the container info be left in the dropbox folder?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly....

You shouldn't mount an encrypted volume, something you presumably value a great deal, into a folder where a third party application uploads the your unencrypted files to "the cloud" At that point your files are only as safe as Dropbox or Sugarsync.

So, you CAN mount it there... but only if you want your stuff to automagically start uploading.